# CodeIgniter URI routing with "#" as path parameter

Tags: php, uri, codeigniter-3

I have a `Home.php` controller and `terms` method in it. I have a url like this: `https://www.example.com/terms` and it works fine.

My `routes.php`:

```
$route['default_controller']   = 'home';
$route['404_override']         = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

$route['terms']     = 'home/terms';
```

Now, I need to change the url to be like this: `https://www.example.com/#/terms` Notice the "#" in-between.

I tried adding this to routes but it didn't work:

```
$route['#/terms']       = 'home/terms';
```

The above change show home page when I open `https://www.example.com/#/terms`

However, if I put any other permitted character `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` mentioned in `conifg.php` in place of # then it works fine:

```
$route['a/terms']       = 'home/terms'; // this works: https://www.example.com/a/terms   
$route['2/terms']       = 'home/terms'; //this works: https://www.example.com/2/terms
```

I also added # in `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` but that too didn't work. Keeps showing home page only.

Also, can anyone explain me why # is not treated the same way as other characters in `permitted_uri_chars`?

Controller is `Home.php` and method is `terms()`. Using CodeIgniter version 3.1.11

Thank You!

**EDIT:**

I need to know if I can achieve it using Codeigniter's routing? Or maybe some rewrite rule using .htaccess?

Comment: Why it is closed as "Duplicate"? I asked if I can do that using codeigniter's routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the web browser, not CodeIgniter. Web browsers treat # and anything after it in a URL to be a reference to an element on the web page pointed by the URL before the # part.

So for a URL https://example.com/#page1, the web browser will make a request to https://example.com/ and then look for an element with ID page1 on the web page.

If you want different pages to load by using a '#' in your URLs, it's done using front-end frameworks like Angular. Check Angular's routing features to understand how it makes the browser load a different view for different URI paths after #.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to know if I can achieve it using Codeigniter's routing? Or maybe some rewrite rule using .htaccess?

Comment: The web browser doesn't even send the part after # to the server. So there's no way that that can be done. As I said, a similar effect can be achieved by using a front-end framework.